# RF low-power limiter

Tags: power, rf

I have designed an RF front end in the 915 MHz ISM band. This front end is for two radios that interface with an SDR.

The TX portion of the front end will transmit 3 W. My problem is that after doing a link budget, if my radios are 1 meter away from each other, then the RX portion on the other radio will have roughly 4 dBm incident. The SDR has a recommended input power of <-15 dBm, so I need my front end to limit the power, not attenuate it.

I have searched for anti-parallel diode solutions, but it seems that I cannot find anything that operates at that low a level.

Here is the link to the SDR [SDR ettus](https://files.ettus.com/manual/page_usrp_b200.html)

[image]
[image]

How can I limit the output level of the front end to -15 dBm to protect the SDR?

Comment: Your question lacks detail. Are you trying to prevent the front end from overloading your SDR, or are you trying to find an SDR with that level of sensitivity?

Comment: So basically the problem is that you have a signal of (how many dBm?) and you want to reduce it down to -15 dBm and you have no clue how to do that?

Comment: I think OP means his SDR requires an input power level 0 dBm > Pwr > - 15 dBm.

Comment: I think it means -15dBm recommended, 0.1dBm has a risk of causing permanent damage

Comment: Just use an attenuator 20db/50 Ohm before SDR to be sure if the ouput front end level is too high.

Comment: Can you provide a schematic of the RF front end?

Comment: Do you want a hard limiter, the equiivalent of antiparallel shunt diodes that will conduct if the signal is too big? Difficult to limit to 0 dBm, can cause distortion to large but non-tripping signals. Or what about an output level sense and gain control. Works well, but very short spikes would get through before the gain got turned down. A gain stage running from a low rail will have a hard(ish) limit, followed by an attenuator which can put the hard limit at any power level, but choose your gain stage carefully for distortion.

Comment: Thank you all for the responses. I do not want an attenuator, because I just want to make sure that the SDR doesn't burn up with signal that are too high. I was thinking of the anti-parallel pair, but I can't seem to find something for that low of power.

Comment: What's the SDR? Link to a datasheet